# Visibility of data with web api and xamarin.forms

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating small project in xamarin.form (to learn xamarin and mvvm pattern ), where my mobile application will be connect to SQL Server database. On every forum people suggest to use Web Api  to get json's from database and next in xamarin application i go under link where is json, parse it and its done. I did an test project which is doing that and it works very well. Unfortunatelly after few days I realized that all data is visible.. If I enter under url/api/subject I get this data in json.

My question is. Should I connect from my xamarin application directly to SQL Database OR is there any way to not showing json's in browser?

Comment: Good idea is to use WebApi, also called as web-services. Your response is displayed in the browser (no matter if it's JSON or XML). You add security to your API by adding authentication or accepting any token which will be unique to each user for each session.

Comment: Adding authentication or tokens is more secure than connect to sql database directly?

Comment: Chanchal is right. Also you can't directly connect your application to database. This is because you have to put your db credentials in the app and allow access to all of the world's ip's to your database. This is a huge security risk. Your database will be hacked the day any user finds this

Comment: Okay then, ill make sth like Chanchal said. Thanks for advices !

Comment: Thank you @It'satrap for the explanation. Grzegorz G, Pleasure is mine.

Answer (score 0):

To function correctly, many mobile applications are dependent on the cloud, and so integrating web services into mobile applications is a common scenario. The Xamarin platform supports consuming different web service technologies, and includes in-built and third-party support for consuming `RESTful`, `ASMX`, and `Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)` services.

This [article](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/) discusses this topics.

For customers using `Xamarin.Forms`, there are complete examples using each of these technologies in the [Xamarin.Forms Web Services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/) documentation.

I recommend you learn more about [REST architecture](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/#REST)

Comment: Yes. I am using it and i like that way. Thing is that informations are visible for everyone. I need to think about hashing these informations and sending them with specific tokens. Its because my project requires no auth (it will be send to specifics devices).

Comment: Oh right! Then you must install [Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth) package in your WEB API and then create an Authorization Server Provider I think this tutorial can help you: http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/